# How to count row numbers in group by sentence

Tags: r, count, group-by, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset like this, let's call it df:

```
Vehicle     Period   Safety.Score
    W01   6/1/2015             45
    W01   6/2/2015             32
    W02   6/2/2015             45
    W02   6/4/2015             35
```

I want to change the Safety.Score column into Average.Score: sum the score of each vehicle and divided by the day numbers, also remove the Period Column. Expected output would be:

```
Vehicle   Average.Score
    W01            38.5
    W02              40
```

What I have done is like this:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
       group_by(Vehicle) %>%
       summarize(Average.Score = sum(Safety.Score) / count(Vehicle))
```

But this doesn't work, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just use the mean? `summarize(Average.Score = mean(Safety.Score))` or if you want to use `sum()` then `summarize(Average.Score = sum(Safety.Score) / n())`.  I don't think you can use the grouping variable in calculations in dplyr.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Scriven. Yeah, I overreact to the issue cause I just start to use R... Sorry for the obviously silly question.

Comment: Not silly.  We all started in the same spot.  Hope you continue to use R!

Comment: That's a sure thing. R is just so powerful. Thanks for you help.